# How to populate a variable with file names in shell

Tags: shell

I have a folder that contains some files and I am trying to populate a variable with the file names separated by comma. This is what i tried so far

My folder containing the required files

```
examples/NMD_DBL1.tiny.bam
examples/NMD_DBL2.tiny.bam
examples/NMD_WT1.tiny.bam
examples/NMD_WT2.tiny.bam
examples/SRR2240277.bam
examples/SRR2240278.bam
```

When I run this, I get the following

```
for i in examples/*bam; do echo $i | cut -d "/" -f 2 | tr "\n" ","; done
NMD_DBL1.tiny.bam,NMD_DBL2.tiny.bam,NMD_WT1.tiny.bam,NMD_WT2.tiny.bam,SRR2240277.bam,SRR2240278.bam,[upendra_35@rogue python]$
```

And when I tried to assign the output to a variable, I am only getting one filename followed by comma

```
for i in examples/*bam; do new=$(echo $i | cut -d "/" -f 2 | tr "\n" ","); done
echo $new
SRR2240278.bam,
```

How can I get all the files into the variable `new` separated by commas like this?

> new=NMD_DBL1.tiny.bam,NMD_DBL2.tiny.bam,NMD_WT1.tiny.bam,NMD_WT2.tiny.bam,SRR2240277.bam,SRR2240278.bam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In bash

Note that the below is only guaranteed to work if your script is run with `bash`, not `sh`; ensure that it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or similar.

To populate an array with your list of files:

```
files=( examples/*.bam )     # put your list of names into an array
files=( "${files[@]##*/}" )  # remove directory names from each
```

To then put the contents of that array into a comma-separated string:

```
IFS=,
files_str=${files[*]}
```

...or, if you don't want to modify `IFS`:

```
printf -v files_str '%s,' "${files[@]}"  # expand the format string '%s,' for each
files_str=${files_str%,}                 # remove the last comma
```

---

#### In any POSIX shell

Arrays aren't guaranteed in baseline POSIX shells, except for one: The argument list. If you don't want to override the global argument list, you can generate a scoped one with a function. Thus:

```
comma_separated_file_list() {
  # check that the first argument exists
  # if it doesn't, then the glob that generated our list came up empty
  [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ] || return

  # consume arguments one at a time, append a "," after each that isn't last.
  while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
      printf '%s,' "${1##*/}"
    else
      printf '%s' "${1##*/}"
    fi
    shift
  done
}

new=$(comma_separated_file_list examples/*.bam)
```

This has the advantage that if no matches for `examples/*.bam` exist, your variable `new` will end up empty (and the `comma_separated_file_list` function will return an exit status of error, which you can branch on).

Answer (score 0):

I think assigning the output of the whole for loop to new should work,

`new = $(for i in examples/*bam; do echo $i | cut -d "/" -f 2 | tr "\n" ","; done)
 echo $new`

Comment: The code didn't worked because there is a space on either side of the `=` and also the output still had `,` at the end. Anyway I figured it out by myself.

Comment: Cool, yep it has the trailing comma. Was just pointing out that the new'd have to be assigned to the output of the bash for loop. Glad it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
files=$(printf "%s," *.bam)   # files a trailing comma
files=${files%,}              # ... but not any more
```

The trick used here is that `printf` has the property that if it has more arguments than conversion specifiers, it repeats the additional arguments through the format string. Obligatory demo:

```
$ printf "(%s - %s)\n" a b c d e f g h
(a - b)
(c - d)
(e - f)
(g - h)
```

So with `"%s,"` we can walk the arguments and add a comma to each one; but of course, we want comma separated, not terminated. The plain old POSIX `${var%pat}` expansion takes care of that.

What if `*.bam` didn't match anything? Then `files` ends up with `*.bam`; might be a good idea to check that.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, with POSIX-defined naming conventions: All-caps names are used for names with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case letter are guaranteed safe for applications to use without interfering with the behavior of POSIX-specified utilities.

Comment: Re: "who cares?" -- anyone who's ever typed `for PATH in` and then wondered why their shell couldn't run any more commands, or `read USER` to get an application-specific username before calling code that assumes `USER` to be the current OS user. It's not an uncommon failure mode.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy POSIX claims the entire `[A-Z]+` space now for the implementation?

Comment: POSIX guarantees that anything outside `[A-Z]+` (that is otherwise a valid name) is safe for applications to use. It's not part of the standard that applications *can't* use that space, but it *is* part of the standard that they're guaranteed not to cause unintended interference with POSIX-specified tooling if they don't. To quote: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Using `PATH` as your own variable would be wrong even there were no claim for a broader namespace in which it happens to sit.

Comment: @CharlessDuffy "they're guaranteed not to cause unintended interference with POSIX-specified tooling if they don't" --- that in fact amounts to it being a reserved namespace!!!  *"I won't zap you with a lightning bolt if you sit in some other chair beside this one"* (not reserved, nope!)

Answer (score -1):

I will answer my own question here

```
new=$(ls examples/*bam | cut -d "/" -f 2 | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$//')
echo $new
NMD_DBL1.tiny.bam,NMD_DBL2.tiny.bam,NMD_WT1.tiny.bam,NMD_WT2.tiny.bam
```